# PanelGrid Issue in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i'm facing a little issue to show my data from data. i'm using ui:repeat tag which is data iterator. in ui:repeat i'm using nested h:panelGrid tags to show my data. for example

```
<ui:repeat data iterator>
<index wise data />
</ui:repeat>
```

I want the following output.

```
<index 1 data><index 2 data>
<index 3 data><index 4 data>
<index 5 data><index 6 data>
```

and so on...

it generates the following output.

```
<index 1 data>
<index 2 data>
<index 3 data>
<index 4 data>
```

this is my code. please have a look.

```
<h:form id="catalog-form">
        <p:poll interval="10" update="catalog-form" /> 
            <ui:repeat  var="product" value="#{productController.bean.products}">
                <h:panelGrid  columns="2"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <p:graphicImage width="80" height="80" value="#{productController.content}" styleClass="rounded-corners">
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{product.productId}" />
                    </p:graphicImage>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Product Name : " />
                        <p:outputLabel  value="#{product.productName}"  />
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                            <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="addCommentBtn" icon="a-icon" onclick="productdlg.show()"  update=":selectedProduct,:comment-form:productIdOut,:show-color-form,:show-camera-form">
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{productCommentController.bean.setProductId(product.productId)}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="commentDlg" icon="comments-icon" onclick="productcmtdlg.show()"  update=":commentProduct,:show-comment-form">
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="featureDlg" icon="feature-icon" onclick="productfeaturedlg.show()"  update=":featureProduct,:show-feature-form">
                                <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: have you tried putting the entire thing in another panelGrid with x columns?

Comment: i have few more things, h:form is wrapped with h:panelGrid, then ui:repeat is wrapped with h:panelGrid. but all in vein. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the ui:repeat as p:dataGrid. 
In p:dataGrid the cloumn attribute is available.
Using that you can display what you want.

```
   <ui:repeat  var="product" value="#{productController.bean.products}">
```

change the above line like this,

```
  <p:dataGrid var="product" value="#{productController.bean.products}" columns="2">
```

Reference : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndGrid.jsf

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think more plain HTML/CSS. Sometimes trying to use to much JSF tags complicate everything for nothing... You can easily change your code to use floating `div` like this :

```
<h:form id="catalog-form" style="width: 500px;">
    <p:poll interval="10" update="catalog-form" /> 

    <ui:repeat  var="product" value="#{productController.bean.products}">
        <div style="width: 50%;float: left;border:1px solid black;">
            <p:graphicImage width="80" height="80" value="#{productController.content}" styleClass="rounded-corners">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{product.productId}" />
            </p:graphicImage>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                <p:outputLabel value="Product Name : " />
                <p:outputLabel  value="#{product.productName}"  />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3"  style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="addCommentBtn" icon="a-icon" onclick="productdlg.show()"  update=":selectedProduct,:comment-form:productIdOut,:show-color-form,:show-camera-form">
                        <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                        <f:actionListener binding="#{productCommentController.bean.setProductId(product.productId)}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="commentDlg" icon="comments-icon" onclick="productcmtdlg.show()"  update=":commentProduct,:show-comment-form">
                        <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton styleClass="btns" id="featureDlg" icon="feature-icon" onclick="productfeaturedlg.show()"  update=":featureProduct,:show-feature-form">
                        <f:actionListener binding="#{productController.setTempProduct(product)}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</h:form>
```

Note I replaced the `h:panelGrid` by a simple `div`, `div`s are 50% of the total width (currently set by the `h:form` but of course I recommand that you change it to the proper element. I've also added a simple `div` at the end only to keep aligment of elements after the `h:form`.